# Variable sendMessageService not initialized in the default constructor

Tags: spring-boot, telegram-bot

I am trying to implement telegram bot via spring boot
Describe a few simple component, but during start a project a get a problem: "error: variable sendMessageService not initialized in the default constructor"
My components:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageHandler {

    private final SendMessageService sendMessageService;

    public void sendMessage(NotificationDto notification) throws TelegramApiException {
        sendMessageService.sendMessage(getMessage(notification));
    }

    private String getMessage(NotificationDto notificationDto) {
        return notificationDto.getMessage();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SendMessageService {

    .....

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws TelegramApiException {
        for (Long chatId : CHAT_IDS) {
            SendMessage sendMessage = generateMessage(chatId, message);
            telegramBotService.execute(sendMessage);
        }
    }
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.8'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'by.teashop.tg'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.telegram:telegrambots:6.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:11.9.1'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-jackson:11.9.1'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:11.9.1'

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Tried a lot of different options with @depensOn annotation, adding @ComponentScan etc..

Comment: Try adding `@Autowired` on top of the field you need. It will indicate to spring boot that this field is a bean that it needs to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already `@RequiredArgsConstructor`  so there is no need for `@Autowired` - Spring Boot will autowire the only-provided constructor automatically.

I am guessing it is because you are missing the `annotationProcessor` of lombok in your dependencies, therefore it doesn't create the constructor. Your `dependencies` should look like this:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.telegram:telegrambots:6.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:11.9.1'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-jackson:11.9.1'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:11.9.1'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

Consider using `https://start.spring.io/` to avoid such problems in the future